# Create html.twig in every pages in drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm newbie in drupal..

Here's the question, Is it possible to create html.twig in every pages? 
Ex: aboutus.html.twig, contact.html.twig?

So that I can easily edit or adding content types for them..same as in default page.html.twig.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my twig debug information in the markup, it sure is possible what you are asking.

You can enable twig suggestions in development.services.yml with this lines:

```
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: true
```

While developing, you might also want to add:

```
cache: false
auto_reload: true
```

so you don't have to clear cache on every twig modification.

Anyway, after adding this and clearing caches, you will see that you can use something like html--front.html.twig or html--node--article.html.twig or any other combination usable with page.html.twig.

Comment: It's great feature in D8! It is not enabled by default. To enable development.services.yml see this page: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!example.settings.local.php/8.2.x

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this article](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions) to get the twig naming convention logic. There are at least three twig template types you have to know about: html.html.twig, page.html.twig and node.html.twig. They are nested.

Let's say your /aboutus page is /node/5

Use node--5.html.twig to alter it's layout.

Comment: I find out that we can used same thingy on html.twig like on the page--front.html.twig I used the other page to be like page--aboutus.html.twig. However when I tried to display the machine name using {{content.machina_name}} it does not display.. Is there something I need to add in my code or convention?

Comment: Probably you're confusing page url alias and content type machine_name.

Comment: Content (node) itself doesn't have machine name. To see all variables available in your template use {{ kint() }}. Make sure Devel Kint module and twig debug mode is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to overwrite a node your have to create a template.

there are two ways you can do this.

first:
create a node and overwrite it ( node--1.html.twig )

second: create a content-type and overwrite its template (more usefull in my opinion because you dont have a "static" node number.)

example:

name the content-type about-us. now you can write a template node--about-us.html.twig and use the field names u declaired: i.e. content.field_text1